# Problems in rebasing in git

Tags: git, github

I am having some problems in rebasing. It is showing conflicts. Actually, I had my local branch started at point A of the remote master branch. But the remote's master branch was rebased with another developer's master branch. So I have commits B-C-D-A at the remote master branch now. At my local branch I have commits A-E-F-G-H now . How am I going to rebase the remote master with my local branch now. It will show some conflicts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take all your commits and rebase them onto the new master:

```
git rebase --onto origin/master A H
```

(replace `origin/master`, `A` and `H` with their respective branchnames/hashes)